# how do i prevent a datepicker from closing after selecting a date?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, datepicker, struts2

had a very important question which has put me in a fix and I could not find the right solution anywhere.

How do I prevent the jquery datepicker from closing after selecting a date? I only want it to close when I click on the cancel or continue button on the datepicker dialogue.

Basically, I want an end date to be displayed on the datepicker which is fetched from the server side code. This should display after I have selected a start date and the the server does some processing on it. Then when I am done, I can click on cancel or continue depending on my choice.

Here is my code:

```
$("#StartDate").datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    inline: true,
    minDate: defaultDate,
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays_document_Scope,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: appRoot + "/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate,inst){
        var expectedDtFromAcc = $("#fromAcc").val();
        var expectedDtToAcc = $("#toAcc").val();
        var tStartDate = selectedDate;
        $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              cache: false,
              url: encodedGetDtUrl,
              data: { tStartDate: tStartDate, expectedDtFromAcc : expectedDtFromAcc ,
                  expectedDtToAcc : expectedDtToAcc }
        }).done(function(output){

            if(output.expectedDate !== null){
                $("#expectedDelDate").val(output.expectedDate);
            }

            var to = $("#expectedDelDate").val();
            var expectedDelDate = toDate(to);

             $("#StartDate").datepicker("option","maxDate",expectedDelDate);
        });
    },
})
.val(defaultDate);
```

Please help me!

By the way I am using Jquery UI v1.12.

Comment: add `$("#StartDate").datepicker({
    autoclose: false`

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
$('#StartDate').datepicker({
    autoclose: false
});
```

Comment: Hey I am not using bootstrap datepicker...Using Jquery Datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this.

```js
$( function(){
  
   $( "#stard_date" ).datepicker({
     onSelect : function(text, obj) {
       
       $( "#end_date" ).show();
       $( "#end_date" ).datepicker({
         defaultDate : '01/09/2017',
       });              
     }, 
     beforeShow : function( inputEle, obj ){
       
       $( "#end_date" ).hide();
     }
   } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div>From: <input type="text" id="stard_date"><div id="end_date" style="display : none;margin-left : 5%; margin-top: 3px;"></div></div>
```

Comment: Hey Ravi..Thanks for your solution..However, the requirement is to show the end date on the same date picker without closing it. I have started research on bootstrap datepicker in the meanwhile.

Comment: Hey ravi ill surely try..but i think i will be using the bootstrap datepicker.